# I cannot get a piece of code to work outside of jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I cannot get this piece of code to work outside of jsfiddle.   I dont understand why it doesn't work from my local server.

http://jsfiddle.net/gHb9F/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>


    <style type='text/css'>
        a, a:visited { color:black }
        a.link.active { color:blue; }
    </style>




    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(function() {
            $('a.link').click(function() {
                $('a.link').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    });//]]>

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>

</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: get any error on console? check that first

Comment: works fine and no error

Comment: Wonder if it's due to `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js` try using `https` instead of `http`.. saying this because I don't have any idea about your local server configuration.. ^^

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary i tried copying the entire code it works

Comment: @Pekka I know it does.. works for me too.. the issue could be with SSL seetings of the server

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to put a document ready inside a window load. It SHOULDN'T make a difference since the promise is already fulfilled and it should fire... but it's redundant and could be eliminated. I don't see anything that needs full window load, so I would go with DOM ready... but that's just me.

Comment: @PeterKA was it for me? I wonder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you are not including correctly the jquery link into your html, try to add this line into your head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   it was because of https!

Comment: @PaulR. yeah! guessed so!!